# External jquery not working in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script named seats.js when i run an html file in chrome or mozilla the file get executed with no any problem. But if i run it in using Internet Explorer 10 the file does not respond.

seats.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
const selections = {};
const inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
const totalElem = document.getElementById("total-container");
const hiddenTotalElem = document.getElementById("hidden-total");
const hiddenSeatElem = document.getElementById("hidden-seats");
const seatsElem = document.getElementById("selected-seats");

for (let i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
  if (inputElems[i].type === "checkbox") {
    inputElems[i].addEventListener("click", displayCheck);
  }
}

function displayCheck(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    selections[e.target.id] = {
      id: e.target.id,
      value: e.target.value
    };
  } else {
    delete selections[e.target.id];
  }

  const result = [];
  let total = 0;

  for (const key in selections) {
    result.push(selections[key].id);
    total += parseInt(selections[key].value);
  }

  // Enable the submit button if at least 1 checked
  $(":submit").prop("disabled",!result.length>0);

  if(result.length>6){
    alert("You can book 6 Tickets only at a time.");
    e.preventDefault();

    // Remove the property added in selections in the code above.
    delete selections[e.target.id];
    return;
  }

  totalElem.innerText = total;
  hiddenTotalElem.value = total;
  seatsElem.innerHTML = result.join(",");
  hiddenSeatElem.value = result;

}





});
```

This html file is here

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by _doesn't respond_, but `const` isn't supported in IE until v11. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I mean the file is not executed

Comment: Check the console, it should be complaining about syntax errors.

Comment: Can you give a help @Barmar i am not good in jquery.

Comment: @Ruckser This has nothing to do with jQuery. IE10 doesn't support some ES5 features like `const`. Change it to `var`.

Comment: Let me try to change @Barmar

Comment: Still not working @Barmar

Comment: What error are you getting now?